# Generate random float numbers in a range with sigma in python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any method to generate non-repeated float random numbers in a range with given size and standard deviation?

I generate e.g. 1000 random floats between a min and max value:

```
randSize= 1000
randValues = np.random.uniform(low=myMinVal, high=myMaxVal, size (randSize,))
```

But I want to generate only numbers, which have less than 0.2 SD in that range

Comment: uniformly distributed or normally distributed?

Comment: e.g. with normal distribution. May be I can also thy uniform distribution later. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear. My understanding is that you want to extract 1000 float from a normal distribution with `mean=0.0` and `sigma=0.2`, to me the easiest way is to use:

```
mu, sigma = 0, 0.2 # mean and standard deviation
s = numpy.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html).

Now, as you know that the probability of obtaining the same float twice is very low, but if this is a requirement, an easy way tackling that is:

```
dim = 1000
original_list = list(set(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 2*dim).tolist()))[:dim]
```

Explanation: I create an `array` of float double the size required, convert to a `list` and then to a `set`. By definition a `set` contains unique values, so potential duplicates are deleted. Now I get back to a `list` and cut it to the size you want: `dim`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I don't want to extract floats from a normal dist. The floats are already created through  `np.random.uniform(low, high, size)` But If I create 1000 random floats sometimes  I get SD from created list, higher than my limit (0.2). My goal is generating random numbers between given min/max values within a included sigma value, so that SD of the total list should not greater than this limit value.